# stuck in implementing search in django

Tags: python, django

I want to implement search in django. I don't use any search technique like solar etc. I am using simple filter query of django.
Now the problem is this: 
I have a model **`Product`**
with five field `name`, `cost`, `brand`, `expiry_date`, `weight`
I want to implement a advanced search feature with all fields,
by:

```
name = request.GET.get('name')
```

I get a value on which basis I search all product.
What I want is that when **`name = None`**, it has to search for all names.
**So problem is this: if values are not coming by user side, how can i search for all names?**

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your search query. However, I think using [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#contains) (or [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) for case insensitive match) will help you solve the problem, with the benefit of being able to search for say first names, last names and names containing a matching text.

You would do:

```
name = request.GET.get('name', '')
search_result = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=name)
```

Notice the `get` method has been instructed to return a `''` instead of the default `None`. And keep in mind that all strings in Python contain the empty string `''`. So when no `name` is sent via the `request`, every `Product` in the DB (with a not *NULL* name) is returned, as their names all contain the empty string `''`.

Comment: when using this and pass 1 variabale out of two it return all result

Comment: I don't understand, you may describe in more detail

Answer (score 0):

if you want when the name is None, you have to search all names in Product Model
try this logic

```
if name == None:
    result = Product.objects.all()
else:
    result = Product.objects.filter(name = name)
```

Comment: `if name is None`, is the most correct way to test for `None` values, as  `None` is a singleton object. More so, the `is` check is done in c which is going to be faster than the equality check done in Python

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = Product.objects.all()
name = request.GET.get('name', None)
if name:
    result = result.objects.filter(name__icontains=name)
```